# Put number of page at the bottom of every page of the document

Tags: numbering, fancyhdr, footer, pagestyle

I am trying to put the number of my pages at the bottom of the page. The document is `\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}`

Using `\fancyfoot{\thepage}` I am able to do it with only a few pages (the first of every chapter). How can I do it with all the pages?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{quoting} 
\usepackage{fancyvrb} 
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{float}

\fancyfoot{\thepage}

\usepackage{mathpazo}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25} 

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Teorema}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollario} 
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposizione} 
\newtheorem{oss}[thm]{Osservazione}
\theoremstyle{definition} 
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma} 

\newtheorem{es}{Esempio}[chapter]
\newtheorem{oss}{Osservazione}[chapter] 

\theoremstyle{definition} 
\newtheorem{defn}{Definizione}[chapter] 

\usepackage{geometry}

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\grd}{\nabla}
\newcommand\dvg{\operatorname{div}}
\newcommand{\rot}{\operatorname{rot}}
\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}
\newcommand{\esssup}{\operatornamewithlimits{ess\,sup}}
\newcommand{\essinf}{\operatornamewithlimits{ess\,inf}}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\lam}{\lambda}
\renewcommand{\th}{\vartheta}
\newcommand{\Om}{\varOmega}
\renewcommand{\Gamma}{\varGamma}
\newcommand{\om}{\omega}
```

Comment: Pleas provide a MWE that we know which packages you're using, which definitions you (probably) already made and so on.

Comment: ok, done @Steradiant

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you just want page numbers at the botom of all pages, then use `\pagestyle{plain}` in the preamble. If you also need headers, you need to be more specific about your document.

Comment: I'm sorry, if it is not very clear. I am still a beginner... So, if I want to move numbers to the botton I have to change also all the headers' settings? 
For example, your suggestion cancels all my headers

Comment: @hellomynameisA have you seen my answer? (if not refresh the page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package *fancyhdr* is more suited for header customization.

But you can use `\pagestyle{fancy}` to activate the page style provided by fancyhdr.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}    
\begin{document}
    The package \emph{fancyhdr} is more suited for header customization.
 But you can use pagestyle{fancy} to activate the page style provided by \emph{fancyhdr}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering! I have a question about your answer: why does it delete all my headers? Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Yes, just comment the `\fancyhf{}` line

Comment: Thank you very much!